# TestNG DataProvider marks as invalid return type Iterator<CustomObject>, but it passes the params into a test method

Tags: intellij-idea, testng, testng-dataprovider

When creating a Dataprovider that returns Iterator I have it in my test method, but my intellij-idea marks this return type as invalid and shows the message:
"Data provider must return either Object[][] or Iterator[], or Iterator".

Here is my class/ method:

```
public class TradeTestDataProvider {

   @DataProvider(name = "experimental")
    public Iterator<TestCase> createCases() throws IOException {
    List<TestCase> test = DataReader.generateCasesFromJson("src/test/resources/json/experimental_test_case");
    return test.iterator();
}
```

}

Please advise, if I am missing something or it is related to TestNG/IDE issue?

**Update:**
I created a post to discuss this issue with plugin:
[topic](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003313839-TestNG-plugin-does-not-support-to-return-Iterator-CustomObject-in-DataProvider)

Comment: Please add your dataprovider class/method as well and please add the code in the form of text/code in the question and not as a screenshot

Comment: It looks intellij-idea plugin issue. Earlier version of TestNG was not supporting single argument and the ide-plugin may not get updated with TestNG updates.

Comment: @user861594, I think, you are absolutely right, cause when I turned off the plugin, the issue disappeared.